# ASP.NET and cookies for remember functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am using cookies to store log on information about a user.

```
Response.Cookies["SiteName"]["U"] = username;
Response.Cookies["SiteName"]["P"] = password;
Response.Cookies["SiteName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(+1);
```

In windows Z i traverse to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies, where the cookies are stored. I want to check if the cookie was actually created. How will i identify the cookie. All this being said, i think the cookies are not being created, anything i am doing wrong, or ideas of how better to create the cookie and check its existence physically.

Comment: I suggest reading this [How to build (and how not to build) a secure “remember me” feature](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/how-to-build-and-how-not-to-build.html) first

Comment: I hope you don't store clear-text password in the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use firebug with firefox, it show easily cookies[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Fiddler](http://Fiddler2.com). It's an excellent tool to analyse http trafic and decrypt cookies